# How to stop one of multilpe of the same goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

As it will be made obvious soon, I am a golang n00b.

I have some go code that starts goroutines based on an event channel. Say it starts 2 goroutines because we receive 2 events of type START.

The goroutine is started with an uri as parameter, which gives us something unique about it.

Later we receive one event of type STOP.

How can I stop the goroutine that was started with the same uri ?

```
for {
            select {
            case event := <-eventCh:
                if event.Entry != nil {
                    switch event.Action {
                    case foo.START:
                        log.Println("uri: ", event.Entry.URI)

                        go func(c chan []byte, u string) error{
                            //awesome goroutine code
                        }(myChan, event.Entry.URI)

                    case foo.STOP:
                        log.Println("uri: ", event.Entry.URI)
                        //I'd like to terminate the goroutine that matches event.Entry.URI
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot stop a goroutine "from the outside". You have to pass some kind of cancellation signal to each goroutine and remember them for later in the main goroutine. A [Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) is typically used as a cancellation signal. The goroutine then has to check for cancellation and exit voluntarily:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
)

type Event struct {
    Action string
    URI    string
}

func main() {
    var eventCh chan Event

    ctx := context.Background()

    cancels := make(map[string]context.CancelFunc) // Maps URIs to cancellation functions.

    for event := range eventCh {
        switch event.Action {
        case "START":
            if cancels[event.URI] != nil {
                panic("duplicate URI: " + event.URI)
            }

            ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
            cancels[event.URI] = cancel
            defer cancel() // cancel must always be called to free resources.

            go func(u string) {
                // Awesome goroutine code

                // Check ctx.Done or ctx.Err in strategic places and return if done.
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return
                default:
                }

                // More awesome goroutine code

                if ctx.Err() != nil {
                    return
                }

                // Even more awesome goroutine code

            }(event.URI)

        case "STOP":
            if cancel, ok := cancels[event.URI]; ok {
                cancel()
                delete(cancels, event.URI)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that your goroutine's `default:` case will need to periodically yield control or it will happily tootle along and never check for whether it received the cancellation `Context` or not.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon, that's what I mean by "Check ctx in strategic places". I hope the update makes it obvious now.

Comment: It does, and thanks for adding it. I have the scars from trying to debug that particular issue!

Comment: Thanks folks for this awesome solution. The map of cancel functions is clever.