# How to release a websocket and redis gateway server resource in golang?

Tags: go, websocket, redis

I have a gateway server, which can push message to client side by using websocket, A new client connected to my server, I will generate a `cid` for it. And then I also subscribe a channel, which using `cid`. If any message publish to this channel, My server will push it to client side. For now, all unit are working fine, but when I try to test with benchmark test by [thor](https://github.com/observing/thor), it will crash, I fine the `DeliverMessage` has some issue, it would never exit, since it has a die-loop. but since redis need to subscribe something, I don't know how to avoid loop.

```
func (h *Hub) DeliverMessage(pool *redis.Pool) {
    conn := pool.Get()
    defer conn.Close()
    var gPubSubConn *redis.PubSubConn
    gPubSubConn = &redis.PubSubConn{Conn: conn}
    defer gPubSubConn.Close()

    for {
        switch v := gPubSubConn.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            // fmt.Printf("Channel=%q |  Data=%s\n", v.Channel, string(v.Data))
            h.Push(string(v.Data))
        case redis.Subscription:
            fmt.Printf("Subscription message: %s : %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
        case error:
            fmt.Println("Error pub/sub, delivery has stopped", v)
            panic("Error pub/sub")
        }
    }
}
```

In the main function, I have call the above function as:

```
go h.DeliverMessage(pool)
```

But when I test it with huge connection, it get me some error like:

> ERR max number of clients reached

So, I change the redis pool size by change `MaxIdle`:

```
func newPool(addr string) *redis.Pool {
    return &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle:     5000,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
        Dial:        func() (redis.Conn, error) { return redis.Dial("tcp", addr) },
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work, so I wonder to know, if there any good way to kill a goroutine after my websocket disconnected to my server on the below selection:

```
case client := <-h.Unregister:
    if _, ok := h.Clients[client]; ok {
        delete(h.Clients, client)
        delete(h.Connections, client.CID)
        close(client.Send)
        if err := gPubSubConn.Unsubscribe(client.CID); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        // TODO kill subscribe goroutine if don't client-side disconnected ...

    }
```

But How do I identify this goroutine? How can I do it like `unix` way. `kill -9 <PID>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop one of multilpe of the same goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246721/how-to-stop-one-of-multilpe-of-the-same-goroutine)

Comment: Looks like you're getting a connection using `conn := pool.Get()`? If you run `go h.DeliverMessage(pool)` an huge number of times, then I guess you might get a "max connections/clients reached" error. Perhaps you should first do `conn := pool.Get()` to see if there is a connection available (will probably block if not so?) and then pass the connection to the goroutine instead of the whole pool.

Comment: You can see on my code has `conn := pool.Get() defer conn.Close()`, if I don't get a pool as param, it will disconnect after I do go delivery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got wrong design architecture, I am going to explain what I want to do.

1. A client can connect to my websocket server;
2. The server have several handler of http, and the admin can post data via the handler, the structure of the data can be like:

   ```
   {
      "cid": "something",
      "body": {
       }
   }
   ```

> Since, I have several Nodes are running to service our client, and the Nginx can dispatch each request from `admin` to totally different Node, but only one Node has hold on the connection about `cid` with "something", so I will need to publish this data to `Redis`, if any Node has got the data, it's going to send this message to the client side.

3.Looking for the NodeID, which i am going to `Publish` to by given an cid.

```
// redis code & golang
NodeID, err := conn.Do("HGET", "NODE_MAP", cid)
```

4.For now, I can publish any message from the `admin`, and publish to the `NodeID`, which we have got at step 3.

```
// redis code & golang
NodeID, err := conn.Do("PUBLISH", NodeID, data)
```

5. Time to show the core code, which related to this question. I am going to subscribe a channel, which name is NodeID. like the following.

   ```
   go func(){
     for {
       switch v := gPubSubConn.Receive().(type) {
       case redis.Message:
           fmt.Println("Got a message", v.Data)
           h.Broadcast <- v.Data
           pipeline <- v.Data
       case error:
           panic(v)
       }
     }
   }()
   ```

6.To manage your websocket, you do also need a goroutine to do that. like the following way:

```
   go func () {
     for {
            select {
            case client := <-h.Register:
                h.Clients[client] = true
                cid := client.CID
                h.Connections[cid] = client

                body := "something"
                client.Send <- msg // greeting

            case client := <-h.Unregister:
                if _, ok := h.Clients[client]; ok {
                    delete(h.Clients, client)
                    delete(h.Connections, client.CID)
                    close(client.Send)
                }
            case message := <-h.Broadcast:
                fmt.Println("message is", message)
            }
        }
      }()
```

7. The last thing is manage a redis pool, you don't really need a connection pool right now. since we only have two `goroutine`, one main process.

   ```
   func newPool(addr string) *redis.Pool {
       return &redis.Pool{
           MaxIdle:     100,
           IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
           Dial:        func() (redis.Conn, error) { return redis.Dial("tcp", addr) },
       }
   }

   var (
       pool        *redis.Pool
       redisServer = flag.String("redisServer", ":6379", "")
   )
   pool = newPool(*redisServer)
   conn := pool.Get()
   defer conn.Close()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#PubSubConn)

You can make your goroutine exit by having a return statement inside your switch case in your DeliverMessage, once you're not receiving anything more. I'm guessing  `case error`, or as seen in the example, `case 0` you'd want to return from that, and your goroutine will cancel. Or if I'm misunderstanding things, and `case client := <-h.Unregister:` is inside the DeliverMessage, just return.

You're also closing your connection twice. `defer gPubSubConn.Close()` simply calls conn.Close() so you don't need `defer conn.Close()`

Also take a look at [the Pool](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Pool) and look at what all the parameters actually do. If you want to handle many connections, set MaxActive to 0 "When zero, there is no limit on the number of connections in the pool." (and do you actually want the idle timeout?)